# Chrome Extension sendRequest and Return the response

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm developng a chrome extension. I have a function which retrieve a JOSN string from Local Storage and return it.

It not working properly, Here is my code.

```
function getstore()
{
    var all = {};
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getlist", key: "" }, function(response) {
        all = JSON.parse(response.data);
        console.log(all); //it prints the JSON properly
        return all; //
    });
}
```

But whenever I'm calling that function like this :

```
var old_a = getstore();// old_a should hold the JSON returned by getstore()
console.log(old_a);
```

But here the value of "old_a" is becoming undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not returning anything from the method `getstore()`.

The sendRequest method has a callback function that it calls when the asynchronous function is finished. The method signature looks like this:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(options, responseCallback)
```

So the responseCallback is the function you added as the last parameter.

```
function(response) {
    all = JSON.parse(response.data);
    console.log(all); //it prints the JSON properly

    return all; // No sense in returning from a callback method, it will do nothing and will never be catched anywhere.
}
```

So what you would want to do is:

```
function getstore()
{
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getlist", key: "" }, function(response) {
        var old_a = JSON.parse(response.data);

        // Use the json object here.
        console.log(old_a); 
    });
}
```